# The property and event halves of the two way binding are not bound at the same target

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to make a two way binding with reactive forms in Angular. I want to transfer the data from the child component to the parent component and back.

My child component HTML:

```
<input type="text" #name class="form-control"
            (keydown)="oss.test(); addNewItem(name.value)"  formControlName="name">
```

My child component TypeScript:

```
  @Input()  namex: string=  "";
  @Output() additem = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

The parent component HTML:

```
 <app-general [(count)]="count" [(namex)]="currentItem" (value)="this.generalInformation=$event; this.print()"
              (isValid)="this.generalInformationIsValid=$event">
            </app-general>
```

The parent component TypeScript:

```
currentItem: string = "";
```

I get following error message:

```
The property and event halves of the two-way binding 'namex' are not bound to the same target.
            Find more at https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works
```

Can someone please help me why I get this error?

I want to get the data from the child component to the parent component and back.

Comment: Did you read the link that it tells you to read? https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works If you read it, it tells you how you should set up two-way binding and why yours is not working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have @Input() namex: string = ""; without @Output() namexChange = new EventEmitter(), try adding the namexChange event

Comment: thank you so much for your answear. It now works! I had a @Output Function but it didn´t end with Change. I think this is something Angular Spezific. Do you know how can I trigger the function on a input field without a button?

Comment: yes, that is the convention that needs to be followed

Comment: how can I save the data back? I have the value now in the other component, but how can I get it back to the input field?

Comment: using a setter with the input decorator, assuming your form group name is myForm and control name is name
@Input()
  set namex(value: any) {
    this.myForm.get('name').setValue(value)
  }

Comment: <input> (value)=this.formGroup.get('namex')</input> I want something like this?

Comment: if you are using reactive forms, Angular recommends setting values through the form control

Comment: ok. something like this """this.form.controls['dept'].setValue(selected.id);""". Where can I set this?

Comment: replace @Input()  namex: string=  "" with @Input() set namex(value: any) { }, inside the setter, you will get the current value which you can set as the control value

Comment: @Input() set namex(value: any) {  this.formGroup.setValue(this.namex)}

Comment: when i type this i get a error message called "value is undefined"

Comment: @Input() set namex(value: any) { his.formGroup.controls['dept'].setValue(value)}

Comment: thanks bro!!! Where do you have this information?

Comment: it is all in the documentation, you have to piece it together  https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Answer (score 0):

Using a setter with the input decorator, assuming your form group name is `myForm` and control name is name

```
@Input() set namex(value: any) {
  this.myForm.get('name').setValue(value)
}
```